# Is there a way to add values to a function in cmd module for python (when using the program)

Tags: python, python-3.x, cmd

I am having issues with the CMD module in python. I need to be able to add values after a do statement like for example:

```
def do_test(self,x,y):
    calculate = x * y
    print (calculate)
```

Ive tried reading the original documentation on the python websites about the cmd.py but im having a hard time understanding any of it as a beginner.

Ive also tried looking for projects that do the same thing i want to do in github, stackoverflow, reddit and youtube. but it seems that the cmd module is used more for static functions that dont get any new values.

```
import cmd
import sys

class TestCMDcmd.Cmd):
    intro = 'Welcome to this simple command prompt'
    prompt = ">>"

# i want to do something like this using the cmd library
def do_test(self,x,y):
    print (x*y)
# psudo code:
'''
def addnumbers (x,y):
    print (x,y)

command = input("addnumbers (4,2)")
if command == add numbers + # some kind of way of writing for example 2     and 4 :
print (addnumbers(inputvalue1 and input value2))



'''

def do_quit(self,arg):
    """Exit command prompt"""
    return True

if __name__ == '__main__':
    TestCMDcmd().cmdloop()
```

Comment: It seems you have a typo around `class TestCMDcmd.Cmd):`.

Comment: Not really the issue :)